# NamespacePrefix of a package vs the namespacePrefix locally defined

Tags: salesforce

When packaging I get a default namespacePrefix for my org.

If I define another local namespace to that environment, than I have two namespaces.

one, I get from the package and one I defined myself.

After reading about the subject, I couldn't understand when querying the db do I get the namespacePrefix of the package and when do I get the namespacePrefix I defined manually.

Which has a priority over the other?

Could I have a collision in this case?

I'm new to salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of packaging is to enable repeatable installation of one or more components of metadata into other orgs.  If you will not be doing this, then I would not use packages.
When you install a package into a destination org, the metadata components in that package take on the namespace of the package, regardless of the source org or destination org's namespace.
Source org namespace: src
Destination org namespace: dest
Package namespace: pkg

If Apex Class myClass and sObject custom__c are both in pkg, then myClass can access custom__c without any namespace.

If Destination org class destClass wants to access custom__c, it must prefix it with the namespace: pkg__custom__c to do so (same's true for the fields on customer__c).

Don't worry too much about your source org, because the purpose of the source org is only for development, assuming you're using packaging for its intended purpose.